# Display screen overlay from component

Tags: react-native

I'm writing a React Native reusable component, which in some state needs to display an overlay on the screen. It seems that the way to do this, is using `position:absolute`. But that does not work very well in my situation, as the component is not child of the root-view and therefore cannot obtain the full screen area.

See this demo example on Snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@dennismadsen/position-absolute-test

In this case the position is obtained based on the position of the `AssetExample` element.

Here is how the above example looks like:

[image: Example screenshot]

I would like the overlay to be positioned in the top of the screen like this:

[image: How I would like the overlay to be positioned]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get the width and height from Dimensions? that way you will always get 100%

import { .....,Dimensions,.... } from 'react-native';

const width= Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height= Dimensions.get('window').height;

Comment: I still think that I would be stocked inside the `AssetExample` element. I would like my overlay to start at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also stuck with the same problem. I've created ListItem input fields where the DatePicker is inside it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using Overlay from react-native-elements.